# css percentage print question

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    dev {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<dev>

<!-- needs a couple of pages to print this -->

</dev>
</body>
</html>
```

%s/dev/div/g

When I print this, the 10 % from the `top: 10%` is related to the size of `one` printed page?

Comment: What is <dev> tag? IMO it should be <div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with prints, it's not recommended using percentages at all, I would recommend using other (Solid) units such as `pt` or `cm`, to make it align perfectly, remember, print is not web, the page size will not change, 10% is not fluid like in a browser. I'd make simple measurements with a ruler and use absolute units.

### As for your question

Yes, it will work, 10% will be 10% from the top of one page.

Comment: Are absolute units independent from the printer-resolution - do pages printed form printers with different resolutions (but equal margins) look all the same?

Comment: Yes, pt is a known unit, so is cm, px might change, I never really tested it with px.

Comment: "the page size will not change" - that's a pretty narrow-minded view in the sense that if you have an international audience, the page size definitely WILL be different. And if you e.g. want to print something relatively simple in a centered manner, using relative units can be a good idea, to spare both the user and yourself from having to deal with page dimension selection.

Answer (score 1):

If you % a tag that spans multiple pages, i believe it only does the the top % in the first instance. Despite there being multiple pages when printing,  creates one giant page. You would have to find the cut off points for each page and close then open a new tag there (i think you mean  not ) although this isn't very good practice.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes... 10% should be from the top of one page, assuming that the element fits on one page.

**However** in my experience, percentages do not work well for print styles.

If possible, it is best to set your styles with `pt` (point), which is the measurement designed for print, or `px` (pixel).

Comment: The tag (div) spans multiple pages.

Comment: Maybe I have understood now: to get the 10% on each page, the element must fit on one page.

Comment: That's my understanding @sid_com